# Undefined variable: $table

Tags: php, variables, undefined

I am getting a Undefined variable: $table   -- everything is returning correctly in my table - if i declare the variable first $table = '' it only returns the last result?

```
output data to tables
            for ($i=1; $i < count($port_number) ; $i++) {
                $port_des_ = substr($port_number[$i], strpos($port_number[$i], "STRING:") + 8);
                $port_des_1 = substr($port_des1[$i], strpos($port_des1[$i], "STRING:") + 8);    
                $speeds_1 = substr($speeds_[$i], strpos($speeds_[$i], "Gauge32:") + 8);
                if(strpos( $speeds_1 , '1000000000' ) !== false){$speeds_1 = "1Gb";}
                if(strpos( $speeds_1 , '10000000' ) !== false){$speeds_1 = "10Mb";}
                if(strpos( $speeds_1 , '100000000' ) !== false){$speeds_1 = "100Mb";}  
                if (preg_match('/40Gig/',$port_des_) & strpos( $speeds_1 , '4294967295' ))$speeds_1 = "40Gb";  
                if(strpos( $speeds_1 , '4294967295' ) !== false){$speeds_1 = "10Gb";}                                       
                $updown_stat_1 = substr($updown_stat[$i], strpos($updown_stat[$i], " ") + 8);   
                    if(strpos( $updown_stat_1 , 'up(1)' ) !== false){$updown_stat_1 = "UP";}
                    else{$updown_stat_1 = "DOWN";}
                $inbytes = substr($in_byte[$i], strpos($in_byte[$i], "Counter32") + 10);
                $outbytes = substr($out_byte[$i], strpos($out_byte[$i], "Counter32") + 10);
                $inerrors = substr($in_error[$i], strpos($in_error[$i], "Counter32") + 10);
                $outerrors = substr($out_error[$i], strpos($out_error[$i], "Counter32") + 10);
                $inucasts = substr($in_cast[$i], strpos($in_cast[$i], "Counter32") + 10);
                $outucasts = substr($out_cast[$i], strpos($out_cast[$i], "Counter32") + 10);
                $inbcasts = substr($in_ncast[$i], strpos($in_ncast[$i], "Counter32") + 10);
                $outbcasts = substr($out_ncast[$i], strpos($out_ncast[$i], "Counter32") + 10);
                $poe_watts = substr($poe_wat[$i], strpos($poe_wat[$i], "SNMPv2") +53);

                // table rows / data
                $table .= '<tr>                  
                <td>'.$port_des_.'</td>
                <td>'.$updown_stat_1.'</td>
                <td>'.$speeds_1.'</td>
                <td>'.$poe_watts.'</td>
                <td>'.$port_des_1.'</td>
                <td>'.$inbytes.'</td>
                <td>'.$outbytes.'</td>
                <td>'.$inerrors.'</td>
                <td>'.$outerrors.'</td>
                <td>'.$inucasts.'</td>
                <td>'.$outucasts.'</td>
                <td>'.$inbcasts.'</td>
                <td>'.$outbcasts.'</td>
                </tr>';
            }               

            echo $table;
```

Comment: Try adding `$table = '';` before the for loop.

Comment: Thanks, This worked -- It also shows -  Undefined offset: 29

Comment: change `for ($i=1; $i < count($port_number) ; $i++)` to `for ($i=0; $i < count($port_number) ; $i++)`

Comment: That put an additional row at the top of my table but did not fix the issue with Undefined offset: 29 in /var/www/html/snmp.php on line 157 - which is the last line before i start my //table rows / data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are declaring `$table` inside your `for` loop.

Add `$table = '';` above your `for` loop.

Comment: Questions that are about undefined variables should not be answered. They should be closed as a duplicate of [PHP: “Notice: Undefined variable”, “Notice: Undefined index”, and “Notice: Undefined offset”](//stackoverflow.com/q/4261133/) only. See: [Should one advise on off topic questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572/1768232). Off-topic questions can be closed and deleted, which could nullify your contribution anyway.

Comment: OK, cheers, noted for the future.